# Compare to dates to see if day of the month falls between them in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to know how I can write a function to check if the 15th day of the month falls within two days. For instance the first field in column b would check to see if the 15th day of the month falls within the first 2 fields in column A. If so (like in this case) it would print true.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 01-06-23 | True |
| 01-20-23 | False |
| 02-03-23 |  |

I'm trying with using wildcards, but evidently it's not as simple as that.

```
=IF("**-15-**">=A2,IF("**-15-**"<=A3,"True","False"),"False")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates are stored as doubles and not a string, so you need to test the day of the month using DAY():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(SEQUENCE(A3-A2+1,,A2))=15))>0
```

This iterates the dates and checks if any are the 15th.

[image]